# htaccess https one page or url including the images/css

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am using this to force my payment page to use HTTPS

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (signup/|payment) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But the images and CSS are on full URLs using the base url set on Codeigniter.

How would I also force those URLs to HTTPS only on my payment page?

Comment: Shoulda used `"//mysite.com/absolute/path/to/image"`

Comment: Thats what the <?=base_url();?> on config is for. thats why I am asking how to force the css js and images to use https also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your base_url inside config.php in

```
$config['base_url'] = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
```

This should fix your problem.